# Corrupted image in iPad simulators when scaling using drawInRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, drawinrect

I'm running my app in the latest Xcode 13 and images that are previously looked as expected, now corrupted when I running the app on iPad simulators.

My code is:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileNameWithExtension];   
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(start_x+2, start_y+2, width-4, width-4);
[myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
```

Now results in black line:

[black line on right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkabu.png)

What can be the reason here?

Comment: `width` is used twice instead of `height`, is this intentional?

Comment: yes, that is square

Comment: Post a [mre] please.